# How to make Sforzando drums SFZ library work with linuxsampler?

Tags: software-installation, audio-player

I have been trying to make the [Sforzando drumkit](https://smmdrums.wordpress.com/for-sfz-sforzando/) with linuxsampler but I always get the "err 3" error tag in red in QSampler shown below the channel count. I have been able to make other libraries work but not this one, please help!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Basically the problem is that some of SFZ files that you load into linuxsampler using QSampler, that reside inside the folder obtained after extracting the [SForzando ZIP file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DHs_jQyNGfls6j3mvyO9F8DpK8vkySLa/view?usp=sharing) appear to be pointing to a higher level in the folder structure.

### Solution 1. Easiest

You just have to move the **Samples** folder inside the **Programs** folder.

### Solution 2. Just for fun

If for any reason you need to preserve the original folder structure. Edit all SFZ adding additional "../" in front of the paths so a path like:

```
sample=..\Samples\SMD Cymbals Stereo (Samples)\Crash (Samples)\Crash 16 (Samples)\RR1\01_Crash_16in_R_edge_RR1.wav
```

would be changed to

```
sample=..\..\Samples\SMD Cymbals Stereo (Samples)\Crash (Samples)\Crash 16 (Samples)\RR1\01_Crash_16in_R_edge_RR1.wav
```

## Explanation

The default folder structure in the plugin files is as follows (well, actually please ignore the "Manual..." folder and file, these as [additional materials](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sahgYlFzKrLWFITU1hY0tSNE0/view?usp=sharing) from the same library I included in the extracted folder):

[image]

The "main" SFZ file is the **SM_Drums_kit.sfz** file, since this contains all instruments. This file makes use of other SFZ files, that are inside the **mappings** folder; this is visible in lines like these ones:

```
.
.
.
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_sidestick.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_rimshot.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_snare65reg.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_snare65nr.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_snare67nr.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_snarehy1.sfz"
#include "mappings/smdrums_sfz_snarehy2.sfz"
.
.
.
```

The files in this folder are expected to point directly to the sampled sounds files in the **Samples** folder. But if you look into those files, they point just a level up from the mappings folder (here one line of the **smdrums_sfz_crash16** file):

```
.
.
.
sample=..\Samples\SMD Cymbals Stereo (Samples)\Crash (Samples)\Crash 16 (Samples)\RR1\01_Crash_16in_R_edge_RR1.wav
.
.
.
```

so these files are pointing to a wrong location, so either you change the location of the Samples folder, or you change the pointers to that folder, which are the `sample=` lines in all those files.